# Estimate size of each group with uncertainties from a KDE plot

Tags: distributions, kernel-smoothing, uncertainty

I want to know the percentage of individuals in the "low-squeak" and "high-squeak" groups with uncertainties. How do I calculate it given the following bimodal distribution?

For example, I need to get the result in the following form:

- "Low-squeak": 20±5%,
- "High-squeak": 80±5%.

[image: Number of penguin squeaks per hour]

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Gaussian mixture models.](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/histogr5.htm)
You basically assume an existence of 2 sub populations in your data.
Fit a model with relevant parameters per each of the populations.
Then using the parameters estimated, you can get estimation of the ratio of each sub population in all of the population.

This [similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/how-to-model-a-bimodal-distribution-of-target-variable) has a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks, when fitting two gaussians M=pϕ1+(1−p)ϕ2, will it be possible not only to get the value but also the uncertainty for the mixing proportion p?